# Assigning an undefined value to a Rhasspy variable

Tags: voice-recognition, home-assistant, assistant

I use [Rhasspy](https://github.com/rhasspy/rhasspy) for my voice assistant and I would like to retrieve the summary of a Wikipedia page with Home Assistant with the following sentence:
"*Search Wikipedia: Leonardo da Vinci*" (Leonardo da Vinci being a variable that can take any value).

The problem is that I don't know how to make a Rhasspy variable take the value of any word after ":".

To do this, I tried the following sentence in Rhasspy:
`(recherches | searches) on wikipedia {query}`

Except that the query variable takes wikipedia as its value, and not one or more words said after wikipedia.